# can we call Spring Remoting web service JAVA From .Net

Tags: java, .net, spring-remoting

We have created Remoting web services using Spring Remoting support.

We need to call those web services from .NET aplication.

Is it possible to do this i.e. calling web services written in java from .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, web services are not language specific, they're either just a REST or SOAP endpoint that can be invoked over HTTP.